# What's the relationship between $|AD|$ and $|EC|$?

Tags: geometry, functions

As shown in the picture, $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, and $\def\degree{{}^{\circ}} \angle ACB = 90\degree, \angle CAB = 30\degree$, $|AB|=2$ .
Point $D$ *(not overlap with $A,B$)* is on the line segment $AB$. Then make a perpendicular line to $CD$ through point $D$ which intersects  ray $CA$ at point $E$.

Let $|AD|=x, |CE|=y$, then what is the relationship between $x$ and $y$ ?

By drawing some possible situations, I find that $y$ decreases and then increases as $x$ increases, and finally goes to infinity. But it's hard to me to find the exact relationship between them.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying $\angle CDE=90^\circ$?  If so, your "vertical line of $CD$ through point $D$ and intersect" might be better written as "perpendicular line to $CD$ through point $D$ which intersects"

Comment: It may be worth using coordinates: $A$ is at $(0,0)$, $B$ at $(2,0)$, $C$ at $\left(\frac32,\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\right)$, $D$ at $(x,0)$ etc.  Find the coordinates of $E$ and the length of $CE$ in terms of $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using law of cosine, $CD^2=x^2+3-2\sqrt{3}x\cos 30^{\circ}=x^2-3x+3\ $.  Also $y=\frac{CD}{\cos \angle ACD}$.

Again, using law of cosine, $x^2=3+CD^2-2\sqrt{3} \cdot CD \cdot \cos \angle ACD \implies \cos \angle ACD=\frac{6-3x}{2\sqrt{3(x^2-3x+3)}}$

Putting it all together, $y=\frac{2\sqrt{3}(x^2-3x+3)}{6-3x}$

As you can see, $y$ goes to infinity as $x$ approaches $2$ (or point $B$) because perpendicular becomes parallel to $AC$. On the other hand, when $x=0, y=AC$.